# Floating licenses in ASP.Net - releasing properly a license

Tags: asp.net, session, licensing

I'm implementing a floating licenses module in my ASP.Net website (Framework 4).

So far, I've chose to assign a license to a user within my LoggedIn method and it works like a charm.

Now, I want to deal properly with the user's disconnection.

Is it correct to react to both the LoggedOut method and the Session_end ? It seems like dupplicating code to me...

What would be the best place(s) to handle a proper disconnection ?

**Edit :** 
I plan on storing each user's license within a session variable.

Comment: `Session_End` only fires if you're using in memory sessions. It doesn't fire if using SQL Server or State Server.

Comment: Good point, I've edited my question :) Actually, I would like to store the license within my session and make sure it's properly cleaned off when the user disconnect. I want to make sure any kind of disconnection is handled properly, and I would like to handle this very simple without dupplicating code !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply put your code in the Session_End & terminate the session when the user logs out.

To terminate the session use:

```
Session.Abandon();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon(v=vs.100).aspx

You might also want to read this page regarding Session-State events:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583(v=vs.100).aspx

> The Session_OnEnd event is supported only when the session state Mode property is set to InProc, which is the default.